# Grep From Command History Giving Different Result Than When I Type It In

Tags: grep, git-bash

When I use a specific grep command from my history, it gives me no results. However, what appears to be the same command from a different spot in my history gives me thousands of lines of results. Below is a copy and paste from my command history. 519 gives me nothing while 520 yields many results. Also, just typing in the command gives me many results.

```
  519  grep -r -i “agm/core”
  520  grep -r -i "agm/core"
```

I am using Git Bash on Windows 10. git version 2.16.2.windows.1

The only thing I can think of is that at some point I used --exclude-dir, so if that flag persisted it could mess with one command and not others? However, I saw nothing about that in the man pages.

Comment: Is the quotes the same for both ,I see the first line has wrong quotes
Also I think you might be missing the file to grep from

Comment: That's super weird. That slight format difference didn't show on my git bash shell or when I was putting it in the text box for this question. I see it now, thanks!